# normal count in loop into another loop AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

my problem is I have a ngRepeat inside another and I need a count starting at 0 that follow 1, 2, 3, 4, etc ...

But I can not, I need help with this because I can not think of anything, here is the link in [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/5h0Rjk9RhMswYqayVRxN/preview).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you need the index for? Why not just implement that functionality in your controller and attach it to the object? 1 more tip - use ng-class to dynamically set the style of your table row.

Answer (score 0):

Spain someone helped me , I leave the solution:

```
    angular.module('app', [])
.controller('groupColorsController', function groupColors($scope){
    $scope.colors = [
        {name : "rojos", color : [
            ["IndianRed", "CD5C5C"],
            ["LightCoral", "F08080"],
            ["Salmon", "FA8072"]
        ]},
        {name : "rosados", color : [
            ["Pink", "FFC0CB"],
            ["LightPink", "FFB6C1"],
            ["HotPink", "FF69B4"]
        ]},
        {name : "narajnas", color : [
            ["Coral", "FF7F50"],
            ["Tomato", "FF6347"],
            ["OrangeRed", "FF4500"]
        ]}
    ];
})
.controller('colorController', function($scope) {
    // $scope -> scope de colorController
    // $scope.$parent -> scope de ng-repeat interior
    // $scope.$parent.$parent -> scope de ng-repeat exterior
    // $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent -> scope de groupColorsController
    $scope.id = 0
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.$parent.$parent.$index; ++i) {
        console.log($scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.colors[i].color.length)
        $scope.id += $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.colors[i].color.length
    }
    console.log($scope.$index)
    $scope.id += $scope.$index + 1;
});

<body ng-app="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="groupColorsController">
            <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                <tbody ng-repeat="colors in colors">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3"><h3><strong>Colores {{colors.name}}</strong></h3></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Código hexadecimal</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="color in colors.color" ng-controller="colorController" style="background-color:{{color[0]}}">
                        <td>{{color[0]}}</td>
                        <td>{{color[1]}}</td>
                        <td>{{id}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

but I could not do AngularJS D: